# How to add only one image by touch

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uiimage, touchesbegan

Working on adding images to a view by touch.  So far my code allows me to add the same image I select as many times as I want when I touch the screen.  I want to be able to just add an image one at a time so I can manipulate the added image (zoom in/out, rotate, move).

How should I modify my code to allow this?

```
 -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
touchPoint = [touch locationInView:imageView];

  if (touchPoint.x > 0 && touchPoint.y > 0)
  {
    stampedImage = _imagePicker.selectedImage;   

    _stampedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:stampedImage];
    _stampedImageView.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
    _stampedImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [_stampedImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y, 80.0, 80.0)];
    _stampedImageView.center = touchPoint;
    [imageView addSubview:_stampedImageView];
    [_stampedImageView release];

  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, you need to subclass UIImageView and implement touchesBegan (and/or gesture recognizer methods) in that subclass. In the code you posted, you should change:

```
_stampedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:stampedImage];
```

to:

```
_stampedImageView = [[CustomImageView alloc] initWithImage:stampedImage];
```

where CustomImageView is your UIImageView subclass.  If you do this, then any touches in the custom view will be handled by the code in that class instead of the containing view.

You will still get the same view added again if you touch somewhere off the subclassed imageView.  If you want to suppress that, you'll have to add a property to keep track of the last picked image and put in an if clause that doesn't add the image view if it contains that image.